# Remove minor tick labels on Python pcolormesh log scale colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, colorbar

I'm trying to make the minor tick labels on my colorbar disappear, and I'm not finding a lot of helpful information online as to how exactly to accomplish this without removing and remaking the ticks completely.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
j = ax.pcolormesh(j_data.columns, j_data.index, j_data.values,
                  norm=clr.LogNorm(), cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm)
cb = fig.colorbar(j, ax=ax, format='%.0e')
```

And here is the result:

[image]

I just want the major 1e0, 1e1, 1e2, etc labels without the labels in between. 
Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Why don't you want to remake the ticks? You could probably do something like `ticks=10**np.arange(3)` (or whatever the range of your data is).

Comment: Primarily because I'm trying to plot multiple sets of data with a function, so I would like to avoid manually making the ticks case-by-case and simply label certain ticks. Although I could probably do this procedurally ... I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I figured out the easy solution - rather than setting ticks manually, I changed the locator from the default (whatever that is for this case) to the ticker.LogLocator(), and that gave me reasonable ticks for the colorbar. I have no idea why the default locator decides to barf ticks all over the colorbar, but the new locator does the trick nicely.